# poisson random variable

Tags: normal-distribution, poisson-distribution

I want to show that  $\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{-n}\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n^k}{k!}=\frac12$

hint = Let $X_n$ be poisson with mean n. Use the central limit theorem to show that P{$X_n\leq n$}$\to\frac12$
 I want to know how to proceed further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} P\left[X_n \leq n \right] = \lim_{n\to \infty} e^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n^k}{k!} $$

and recall that a Poisson random variable with large mean(and variance) can be approximated well by a Normal random variable. In the limit the approximation becomes exact.

Therefore

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} P\left[X_n \leq n \right] = \lim_{n\to \infty} P\left[ \frac{X_n - n}{\sqrt{n}} \leq 0 \right] = P\left[ Z \leq 0 \right] = \frac{1}{2}$$

where we have used the symmetry of the standard Normal variable.